# how to make SEO friendly url

Tags: php, html, mysql, .htaccess

My dynamic url is

```
http://www.example.com/hamlyn/page.php?id=14
```

How can I make this url short or search-engine-friendly?

Comment: Learn HTACCESS - URL Rewrite..That answers your question, so your url will be `http://www.developer.nextgenexperts.in/hamlyn/page/14`

Answer (score 2):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)$ page.php?id=$1
```

The above will help you have url like:

```
http://www.example.com/hamlyn/page/14
```

which will map to

```
http://www.example.com/hamlyn/page.php?id=14
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I made some changes to it. Please check again.

Comment: yes, i have put this file, inside hamlyn folder. and when i open http://www.developer.nextgenexperts.in/hamlyn/page.php?id=14 link the url is not redirect..

Comment: Can you try putting the htaccess file one directory up?